# Importing Python package to Azure Function takes too long time

Tags: python-2.7, azure, azure-functions

In my Azure Function, I install and import some package such as: cv2, numpy, azure, pydocumentdb. I calculated the time it takes to import those libraries, it is about 20s.

What are the reasons? Do you have any solution for this? I am using Python 2.7.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue with python packages -- see this github issue for more details: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1626

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, the time you took is expected when you install and import package into Azure Fuctions.

This is logical, since that files in your package might contain decorators, library calls, inner constants, etc. So it can take a long time if there is a program written in the module or when you import a large amount of `additional libraries` in your package.

Furthermore, although the code itself is not executed, the `interpreter` will analyze the function in Azure Function. It will transform the source code into a syntax tree and do some analysis (which variables are local, etc.).

You could alse note that a package typically has an `__init__.py` file, that initializes the package. That file is also executed and can take considerable time as well. For instance some packages that have a database connection, will already set up the connection to that database, and it can take some time before the database responds to the connection.